# Duplicate methods due to type erasure in spite of @specialized

Tags: scala, type-erasure

Stumbled over that

```
def foo(f: Int => Unit) {}
def foo(f: Long => Unit) {}
```

doesn't compile because of `method foo is defined twice`. I know that above is only a shorthand for

```
def foo(f: Function1[Int, Unit]) {}
def foo(f: Function1[Long, Unit]) {}
```

and that after type erasure both methods have same signature.

Now I've read in [Try out specialized Function1/Function2 in 2.8.0 RC1!](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Try-out-specialized-Function1-Function2-in-2-8-0-RC1-td1957121.html) that `Function1` and `Function2` have `@specialized` versions for `Int`, `Long` and `Double` since Scala 2.8. That surely means that `Function[Int, Unit]` and `Function[Long, Unit]` have separate class files at JVM level.

Would then not both signatures are different?

Is the problem, that second type parameter will continue to be erased? But same problem with

```
class Bar[@specialized T]
def foo(f: Bar[Int]) {}
def foo(f: Bar[Long]) {}
```

it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@specialized has nothing to do with type erasure, at least in this case. It means that an extra version of your class is generated with the native type in the position. This saves on boxing/unboxing notably.

So you define a class like:

```
class MyClass[@specialized(Int) T] {
  def foobar(t: T) = {}
}
```

and you get two classes as output, (approximately):

```
class Foobar[java.lang.Object] {
  def foobar(t: java.lang.Object) = {}
}

class Foobar[int] {
  def foobar(t: int) = {}
}
```

You need to have two implementations of the class because you can't always guarantee that the one with the correct native type will be called. The scala compiler will choose which one to call. Note that the java compiler has no idea this specialization is taking place, so must call the unspecialized methods.

In fact, the output is the following (via JAD):

```
public class MyClass implements ScalaObject {
    public void foobar(Object obj) { }

    public void foobar$mcI$sp(int t) {
        foobar(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(t));
    }

    public MyClass() { }
}

public class MyClass$mcI$sp extends MyClass {
    public void foobar(int t) {
        foobar$mcI$sp(t);
    }

    public void foobar$mcI$sp(int i) { }

    public volatile void foobar(Object t) {
      foobar(BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(t));
    }

    public MyClass$mcI$sp() {}
}
```

So your type erasure problem will not be fixed with @specialized.

Answer (score 3):

Both for compatibility and for cases where the type parameters of `Function1` are unknown, a method with the signature as if `Function1` was not specialized must also be generated.

Comment: Does this mean that if I define `def foo(f: Bar[T]) {}` the compiler really defines a `def foo(f: Bar[Int]) {}` and `def foo(f: Bar[Long]) {}` automatically and there would be no need for defining they explicitly?

Comment: @binuWADa: No it doesn't, look at [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133993/duplicate-methods-due-to-type-erasure-in-spite-of-specialized/8140954#8140954).

Answer (score 0):

Inspired especially by [Matthew Farwell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836/matthew-farwell)'s answer I've tried the following

```
class Bar[@specialized(Int) T](val t: T)
class Foo {
  def foo(b: Bar[_]) { print(b.t) }
}
val bari = new Bar(1)
print(bari.t)
foo(bari)
```

with `scalac -print` and got:

```
// unspecialized version Bar[_] = Bar[Object]
class Bar extends Object with ScalaObject {
  protected[this] val t: Object = _;
  def t(): Object = Bar.this.t;
  def t$mcI$sp(): Int = Int.unbox(Bar.this.t());
  def specInstance$(): Boolean = false;
  def this(t: Object): Bar = {
    Bar.this.t = t;
    Bar.super.this();
    ()
  }
};
// specialized version Bar[Int]
class Bar$mcI$sp extends Bar {
  protected[this] val t$mcI$sp: Int = _;
  // inside of a specialized class methods are specialized,
  // so the `val t` accessor is compiled twice:
  def t$mcI$sp(): Int = Bar$mcI$sp.this.t$mcI$sp;
  override def t(): Int = Bar$mcI$sp.this.t$mcI$sp();
  def specInstance$(): Boolean = true;
  override def t(): Object = Int.box(Bar$mcI$sp.this.t());
  def this(t$mcI$sp: Int): Bar$mcI$sp = {
    Bar$mcI$sp.this.t$mcI$sp = t$mcI$sp;
    Bar$mcI$sp.super.this(null);
    ()
  }
}
class Foo extends Object with ScalaObject {
  // scalac compiles only ONE foo method not one for every special case
  def foo(b: Bar): Unit = Predef.print(b.t());
  def this(): Foo = {
    Foo.super.this();
    ()
  }
};
val bari: or.gate.Bar = new or.gate.Bar$mcI$sp(1);
// specialized version of `val t` accessor is used:
Predef.print(scala.Int.box(bari.t$mcI$sp()));
Foo.this.foo(bari)
```

But through `foo` only the unspecialized version of `val t` accessor is used, even for the specialized instance `bari` and indirectly `bari`'s overridden method `def t(): Object = Int.box(Bar$mcI$sp.this.t());` is called.